# Markdown comment within table

Tags: markdown, slate

I am looking for a way to add comments specific to different rows in a Markdown table (parsed by [Slate](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=EFZ&channel=fs&ei=bLr5XuOWJraGwPAP_ry6sAo&q=slate%20api%20documentation&oq=slate%20api%20docu&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgIIADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIABBDOgUIABCRAlDEKFjkL2DmN2gAcAF4AIABswGIAfAHkgEDNC41mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab)). I don't want them to appear in the HTML generated from this Markdown file.

I haven't found any comment syntax which works in this setting. I tried

```
[]: # (comment)
[]: # "comment"
[]: # 'comment'
[//]: # (comment)
[comment]: # (comment)
<!-- comment -->
```

and variations of them, could not get anything to work.

Have any of you already succeeded to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to add an extra column to the table on the relevant rows, e.g.

```
Name | Description 
--------- | ------- 
first item | description | comment
second item | description
```

With this the comment never appeared in the generated HTML.
I don't know if it is good practice and how portable it is though.